# Accesing button in nested form symfony (child of a child) in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

This is form i use:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new NewsType(), $news)
            ->add('edit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'edit'))
            ->add('delete', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'delete'))
            ->add('comments', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type'   => CommentType::class));
```

CommentType:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('author', TextType::class)
        ->add('text', TextType::class)
        ->add('remove', SubmitType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment'));
}
```

Is it possible to access remove button from CommentType so when its clicked to delete comment entry. Everything is mapped properly, i can see comment objects displayed on my page, but when i use `$form->get('remove')` i get `"Child "remove" does not exist."` Is it even possible to do this way?

Comment: `if($form->has('delete') && $form->get('delete')->isClicked())` ? But I dont know if it is possible with CollectionFormType

Comment: `if ($form->get('edit')->isClicked())` works fine with button called `edit`. i want to use button called `remove` from CommentType

Comment: Exactly. I have no clue if this is possible. Maybe we ask @webmozart?
EDIT: Just asked him on Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access a grand grand child doing:

```
foreach ($form->get('comments') as $entry) {
    $toRemove = $entry->get('remove')-isClicked();
    // handle it ...
}
```

But to submit it separately you must ensure that your building the "complete" child form in your view:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{% for child in form %}
    {% if 'news_comments' == child.vars['full_name'] %}
        {{ form_start(child) }}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
        {{ form_end(child) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) %}
```

Aside note:

be careful, you seem to use symfony 2.8 and to have updated the FQCN for the form types, but it's needed too for creating the form:

```
$form = $this->createForm(NewsType::class, $news)
```

Comment: this is my code from template 
`{% for comment in form.comments %}
{{ form_row(comment.author) }}
{{ form_row(comment.text) }}
{{ form_row(comment.remove) }}
{% endfor %}`  
and using `$form->get('comments')->get('remove');` still gives me 
`Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\OutOfBoundsException: "Child "remove" does not exist."` error

Comment: You should simply do `{{ form_row(form.comments) }}`

Comment: then it displays numbers in front of the comments but that's not important. it displays comments but cannot check if button is clicked because i get error no matter how i display template.